# Unable to use If/Elif/Else Statements in Selenium -- Determining Existence of Element

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I'm trying to build a webscraper for google search results & have come up with 3 scenarios to deal with:

1. A pop-up box appears with the information I need and extract that
   [Pop Up Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNbOY.png)
2. The text below the header has the information & I extract that
   [Text below header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiVty.png)
3. No useful information - I just grab the link
   [Grabbing link itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNDcv.png)

Here's my code, I assumed using an "if" statement meant that if the webdriver couldn't detect the element, that meant it would move on to the next line of code. However, I'm faced with this error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".hgKElc"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

I specifically chose this class name because I knew it would be absent from certain pages (in #2 and #3) streamlining the process. How can I get the machine to ignore when an element is not found & move onto the next thing?

My code:

```
#preparing brand name
brand_name = 'agentnateur'
sh_brand_name = brand_name.lower().replace(' ','')


#google search
wd.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(3)
subject_box = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name=q]')
search_stg = '@'+ sh_brand_name +'.com contact us'
print(search_stg)
subject_box.send_keys(search_stg)
subject_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)

#extracting information -- case 1 pop up box
html = wd.page_source

if wd.find_element_by_class_name('hgKElc'): 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class_name('hgKElc')
  print('yes1')
elif wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Contact')]"): 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Contact')]")
  print('yes2')
elif wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'contact')]"): 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'contact')]")
  print('yes3')
else: 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class('yuRUbf').find_element_by_css_selector('#rso > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.yuRUbf > a')
    

print(email_address)
wd.quit()
```

I've tried 3 blocks of try, exception but that doesn't work because I need the loop to keep running for later iterations. To do that, I'd ideally need a continue function but that doesn't work in try, exception blocks.

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if wd.find_elements_by_class_name('hgKElc'): 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class_name('hgKElc')
  print('yes1')
elif wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Contact')]"): 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Contact')]")
  print('yes2')
elif wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'contact')]"): 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class('aCOpRe').find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'contact')]")
  print('yes3')
else: 
  email_address = wd.find_element_by_class('yuRUbf').find_element_by_css_selector('#rso > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.yuRUbf > a')
```

find_element returns a webelement else it throws exception if element is not present. You cnannot use it for  driving conditional branches like if.

use find_elements , instead. THis returns an list that contains the webelements matching the locator or an empty list if no elements are found

in python

### empty list [] is False and non empty list [1,2,3] is True